# Sending POST data to website returns missing value for parameter

Tags: post, postman

I am using Postman to send POST and I want to receive json response like on image below: [image]
The request is below:
[image]
The problem is I am receiving this error: **"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'page'."**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is telling you right? Does 'page=1' return anything? Are they URL params or form-data params?

Comment: 'page=1' returns same error... I am not sure, can you tell by the screenshot I posted? How can I check that?

Comment: What the API accepts as params, either URL or form-data ones, are determined by the implementation of the API. I don’t know what that is so I wouldn’t know - Do you own it?

Comment: API accepts URL parameters sent by POST.

Comment: There’s not a lot that people can do given the lack of information and context - You’re request is a good one 200 OK but the response in telling you there is a params missing. Maybe open a new tab and create a new request using the minimum required properties and work from there?